# How gmail implements 'add link to mail' function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gmail

I want to know how gmail implements its **add link to mail** function - is it a div which changing it's display? Is it another layer? Or is it something else?

Thanks in advance,

oz radiano.

Comment: Voted to close for "not a real question". I'll remove vote if you can clarify what you mean.

Comment: oz, do you mean in the compose mail screen, if you switch to rich editing and it has a little toolbar above the message textarea with different formatting options, one of them being add link?

Comment: @Triptych: it was a poorly worded question, maybe, but voting to close and downvoting is not the right way of going about it...

Comment: I edited the question... replaced the word 'mail' with the text which is bold.

Comment: Yeah didn't realize I couldn't remove close votes.  Then again, the OP revenge-downvoted me on two other questions, so I guess we're even.

Comment: @Triptych: Not likely, with a rep of 21...

Comment: @jeroen, and no votes.  You're right.  But someone sure downvoted my two most popular answers within 1 minute of me downvoting this question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about one of these?

#### Add link form

[GMail Add Link 1 http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/thumbnails/bxpwxqpauzxe.png](http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/jrwddejjnheh.png)

#### Floating link toolbar

[GMail Add Link 2 http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/thumbnails/rrdkcg_tuqjfypvmlra.png](http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/rrdkcg/tuqjfypvmlra.png)

(click images to enlarge)

**Edit:**

The main secret is that you want to pull your box out of the flow of the HTML. This is easily done using `position: absolute;` and then position the box using `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom`.

For example, here's a code snippet ([full code example](http://pastry.se/10100/)):

```
.box {
    background: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    left: 2.00em;
    padding: 2.00em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.00em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous javascript server callbacks with DOM manipulation. More then just swapping out the html in one big div, but updating things only where they need to be and when they need to be.